# How to write integration test cases for the two activities in android

Tags: android, testcase

Actually i am new to test case here i go on with the integration tests for the two activities.

Below code:

```
public class MainActivityFunctionalTest extends
    ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

  private MainActivity activity;

  public MainActivityFunctionalTest() {
    super(MainActivity.class);
  }
  @Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
    activity = getActivity();
  }

  public void testStartSecondActivity() throws Exception {



    // add monitor to check for the second activity
    ActivityMonitor monitor =
        getInstrumentation().
          addMonitor(SecondActivity.class.getName(), null, false);

    // find button and click it
    Button view = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    // TouchUtils handles the sync with the main thread internally
    TouchUtils.clickView(this, view);

    // to click on a click, e.g., in a listview
    // listView.getChildAt(0);

    // wait 2 seconds for the start of the activity
    SecondActivity startedActivity = (SecondActivity) monitor
        .waitForActivityWithTimeout(2000);
    assertNotNull(startedActivity);

    // search for the textView
    TextView textView = (TextView) startedActivity.findViewById(R.id.resultText);

    // check that the TextView is on the screen
    ViewAsserts.assertOnScreen(startedActivity.getWindow().getDecorView(),
        textView);
    // validate the text on the TextView
    assertEquals("Text incorrect", "Started", textView.getText().toString());

    // press back and click again
    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);

    TouchUtils.clickView(this, view);
  }
}
```

Below line which calls SecondActivity gives me null pointer error how can get the value for second activity tried a lot to fix but remains the same.

**SecondActivity startedActivity = (SecondActivity) monitor
        .waitForActivityWithTimeout(2000);**

If anyone have idea about this please help me.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot readily do integration testing using `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`. This is what **`uiautomator`** was created for.

Comment: can you please guide me through any tutorials

Comment: as i am new to test case can u please guide me